# Symfony2 / SonataAdmin : Got an CSRF Error when trying to update a record

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

Working on a symfony2 project with mongodb odm, I try to setup sonata-admin.

I was able to:

- setup sonata on 2 kinds of ODM documents
- list

But when i'm trying to update a record, I have currently a problem of CSRF.
I tried for both kind of records.

```
An error has occurred during update of item "AppBundle\Document\Domain:0000000013e9983500007fbae117c6a0".
 The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.
```

It seems the CSRF token is present in the source code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="s57a195b9a533f__token" name="s57a195b9a533f[_token]" class=" form-control" value="W-pG62dT7hn6mHUu15bQQ4ChU0P55w9pmXsfP7HDnQE" />
```

I am using Apache. Rewriting module is enabled.

Here is my setup:

**Sonata Bundles**

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www/publishr$ php composer.phar show sonata-project/*
sonata-project/admin-bundle                  3.x-dev 7386ec0 The missing Symfony Admin Generator
sonata-project/block-bundle                  3.1.1           Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                         1.0.7           Cache library
sonata-project/core-bundle                   3.0.3           Symfony SonataCoreBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle 3.x-dev 1157efc Symfony Sonata / Integrate Doctrine MongoDB ODM into the Son...
sonata-project/exporter                      1.6.0           Lightweight Exporter library
```

**Symfony Bundles**

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www/publishr$ php composer.phar show symfony/*
symfony/assetic-bundle     v2.8.0  Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/monolog-bundle     2.11.1  Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge     v3.1.3  Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu      v1.2.0  Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu  v1.2.0  Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring  v1.2.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php56     v1.2.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php70     v1.2.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util      v1.2.0  Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/security-acl       v3.0.0  Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle v2.3.11 Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony            v3.1.3  The Symfony PHP framework
```

**PHP version**

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www/publishr$ php -v
PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: If I disabled in FormTypeCsrfExtension.php the "defaultEnabled" to false. The record is updated.

Comment: Yeah but then you no longer have protection against CSRF

Comment: You should try to do step by step debugging in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/EventListener/CsrfValidationListener.php`

Comment: I know that i did not have protection agains CSRF. But it was better than nothing ;-) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.
It's linked to my vagrant setup.

could solve my problem now. It seems to be a problem with write permissions on the session save path. If I change the configuration to use the default session save path as following:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        save_path: null
```

Then `/var/lib/php/session` is used instead of `/var/www/myproject/app/cache/dev/sessions`.

Then it's working!

Comment: You should really consider setting permissions properly though. If you can't write to app cache, you are going to have other problems. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html